# Read 2 lines at a time from a text file and assign it to variables in shell script

Tags: shell, while-loop

I have a text file with 50 numbers. I want to read 2 lines at at time assign it to variables

input.txt:

```
129260
129288
129356
129384
```

read input.txt ( 2 lines at at time)

```
$VALUE1=129260
$VALUE2=129288
```

Put a loop to keep on doing it till entire file is read.

Comment: How do you want to assign 50 values to 2 variables? Only use the last 2 values, add them, or use 50 variables?

Answer (score 3):

This reads in two lines at a time from `input.txt`, assigns each line to a variable, and displays the values of the variables:

```
$ while read -r val1 && read -r val2; do echo "val1=$val1 and val2=$val2"; done <input.txt
val1=129260 and val2=129288
val1=129356 and val2=129384
```

Comment: It's unlikely that the first read would fail and the second succeed, but it seems better to write this as `while read -r val1 && read -r val2` to avoid that (pathological) case.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you.  That is good defensive programming.  Answer updated to use `&&`.